# How can I read all the key-value pairs in .ini file into an object?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey, ini

Let's say I have an .ini file with the following key value pairs

```
[keys]
a:"apple"
b:"banana"
o:"orange"
```

How can I read these key,value pairs into an object (associative array) in my script?

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. If so please verify my answer :D Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a ton man , It worked just great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
A:=Object() ;Create Array/Object
Loop, read, listing.txt   ;loop through file
{
    IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, [keys] ;if line has [keys] in it continue
    { 
        continue
    }
    ;fill array with line split on :
    A[StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, "`:").1] :=StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, "`:").2  
}
;print key , value for A
For key, value in A
    MsgBox %key% = %value%
```